# iOS upload to App Store from Xcode do not show the libraries Google Fabric and Crashlytics in IPA content list

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, crashlytics, google-fabric

[image]I have recently added the libraries Google Fabric and Crashlytics to my project and try to upgrade my app in iTune .Crashlytics works fine for me and it show the error report in it's dashboard. 
But when I take archive, it do not show these libraries in IPA content. I can see all other libraries e.g.:. NoChat  Please see the screenshot.
Is it normal?

Comment: Where is the screenshot ?

Comment: It depends on how you integrated them. Are they pods? Your IPA summary will only show the items that you are codesigning, so if those frameworks are already signed, they won't show up in your summary.

Comment: sorry Sneha, screenshot uploaded..

Comment: Yes David, they are in Pods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see this is normal, it happens to my app as well and I use `Crashlytics` and `Answers` (`Fabric`).

[image: Missing .frameworks]

I suspect they do something with both frameworks when they execute `"${PODS_ROOT}/Fabric/run"` which is added as a `Run Script` in `Build Phases`.

To recap, it should be OK and for my apps I get crashes and answers as I should...